# how to use a variable as QML Element id

Tags: javascript, qml

I have a 100 element of same type in My QML File with the ids of "input0" to "input99" that has a property with type of string named text and i want to use a loop to push all the string into a array in JavaScript
i tried to use a loop like this and but nothing works and the array remains empty:

```
function gather(){
var array=[]
for (var i =0;i<100;i++){
{array.push(("input"+i).text;
console.log(array[i];}
}
```

I get the following log:

```
(gather): qml: undefined
```

I'm on QtQuick 2.7

how can i do this ?

**EDIT: With the suggestion of *derM* it tried the following:**

```
Flickable{
    TextField{
        id:input1
        text:"text1"
    }
    TextField{
        id:input2
        text:"text2"
    }
    TextField{
        id:input3
        text:"text3"
    }
    TextField{
        id:input4
        text:"text4"
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var textArray=[]
        for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            var c = Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.0; QtObject { function f() { return input" + i + ".text } }", this, "none")
            textArray.push(c.f())
            console.log(textArray[i])
            c.destroy()
        }
    }
}
```

It still does not work. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Are those inputs children to an `Item`?

Comment: its TextField most of the elements

Comment: I was not asking, what kind of `Item`s your inputs are. I was asking for their parent. Are they all children of the same `Item` or not?

Comment: they are children to a gridLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want/need to grab them by `id` you need to translate from a `string` to an `id`, which is not very performant, and can't be done with `('myStringHere')`.

The only way I can think of right now, is dynamic object creation with [`Qt.createQmlObject()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createQmlObject-method) where you create a dummy object, containing a function, that returns the desired object.

**Example:**

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("PathView path test")

    Text {
        id: myText1
        text: "hallo"
    }

    Text {
        id: myText2
        text: "world"
    }

    Text {
        id: myText3
        text: "and"
    }

    Text {
        id: myText4
        text: "stuff"
    }

    property var textArray: []

    Component.onCompleted: {
        for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            var c = Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.0; QtObject { function f() { return myText" + i + ".text } }", this, "none")
            textArray.push(c.f())
            c.destroy()
        }
        console.log(textArray)
    }
}
```

But as this dynamic object creation is not the most performant, I would rather not do it.

If by chance, all of those `inputXX` are children of the same parent, you might instead just crawl the parent's `children`-property. If you need to make sure, that the `id` is proper, also set the `objectName` to be the same as the id, as [you can't query the id](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#the-id-attribute).

**EDIT** As all the inputs are children to the same `GridLayout` you can proceed with the second approach: *looping over the `GridLayout.children`* like this:

```
function collectTexts() {
    var a = []
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i].text) {
            a.push(children[i].text)
        }
    }
    return a
}
```

As there might be other `children` that have a `text`-property, it is advisable to set the `objectName`-property e.g. to `inputXX` and check if the `objectName` matches this pattern before adding it to the `array`.

---

**EDIT: Regarding your second try**

In the code, where you tried to adapt my solution, the parts of my code are fine. What does not work is, how you handle the array.

Your loop starts with `i = 1`. So you successfully push `input1.text` into the array. The indices of the array however start with `0`, so the first element that you just pushed is in `textArray[0]` - you print `textArray[1]` which is still `undefined` - thus this output. You can fix that code by simply replacing the line

```
console.log(textArray[i])
```

by

```
console.log(textArray[i - 1])
```

Comment: Dynamic Object creation cannot work cause every input has a different name and position on the screen

Comment: You only create dummy objects, that will do the accessing for you, not the `inputs` themselves. The only thing you need to make sure of, is that the dynamic objects are in the correct scope, to resolve the id names.

Comment: You should try out suggested code, before saying, it would not work.

Comment: i tried it and i added console.log after push to see the entery and i still get `(onCompleted): qml: undefined` even with text in it.

Comment: Please share the code of your last attempt. Maybe I can help you fix it. Please share a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i used it in a simple file to to know that it works .i droped positioning and all the other stuff . first i tried it on a button instead of component which failed

Comment: Show me your code please. I can't help you any further, by blindly guessing, what you might have written. Because the example posted by me works. So there must be anything strange about your code, that it does not work.

Comment: i did .its above this answer its pretty simple but if u want i upload the whole code

Comment: The code you wrote, when having my answer in your mind. I don't need 100 inputs. Make it two or three, but in a realistic structure. That the code of your question won't work is pretty obviouse, as the JIT can't know when you suddenly talk about an `id` when you give him a `string`, and when you simply mean the string itself.

Comment: so u mean there's no way to do this in a `for` and i need to assign them 1 by 1?

Comment: No, you just had a minor mistake, when implementing my method, by outputing the wrong index of the array. Sorry I overlooked your appendix in an answer (as this is not to be expected on StackOverflow)

Comment: Thanks That Solved My Problem

Comment: Then please don't forget to accept and upvote my answer :-)